# How to concatenate an interval of files using 'cat'?

Tags: unix, cat

I have multiple files numbered as file_1.mol file_2.mol and so on. I'd like to concatenate the files in groups of 20 files, creating the file_1-20.mol. Is it possible to define an interval in the 'cat' command to get this result?

thanks in advance

Comment: You can `for` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use brace expansion:

```
cat file_{1..20}.ml > file_1-20.mol
```

or make a shell function that you can pass the start and end numbers to:

```
copy_range() { cat file_{$1..$2}.mol > "file_${1}-${2}.mol" }
copy_range 1 20
```